# Regex to find aadhar number

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a unique number from a string that contains 4 numbers separated by spaces in between them ***(not at the start and end)***, and the occurrence of these numbers should be 3.

I've tried like this, but it gives me numbers with and without spaces, which I don't want. It should only contain spaces in between them.

**Example**

```
(\d{4}.?){3}
```

above regex selects these as correct

1. `2131 2312 3675`
2. `2131231212313675`
3. `2131 1231 3675`   *- (this includes spaces at start & end)*

In option (3) I can ignore spaces but I don't want output as option (2).

How can I fix this?

Live [example](https://regex101.com/r/evpzO2/1)

Comment: What is you replace the `.` by `\s`? And then probably replace the `?` by `+`.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari: You can use: `\b\d{4}(?: \d{4}){3}\b` check demo: https://regex101.com/r/F6Ij3i/1

Comment: @user3783243 `\h` is not a space character that I know of. The "re" module documentation doesn't list `\h` at all. An actual space is a space character in a Python regex, while `\s` is (any) whitespace character.

Comment: @user3783243 I forgot instead of `.?` I've tried to use `\s` but it combines next 4 digits that I don't want I'll update my pattern in my question

Comment: @user3783243 Not in Python, and this question is tagged [python]. You'll get an error in Python.

Comment: Hello @user3783243 `\h` is valid for ***Perl, PCRE (C, PHP, R)*** not for python as @9769953

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for helping me especially @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```bash
\b\d{4}(?: \d{4}){2}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F6Ij3i/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `\d{4}`: Match 4 digit
- `(?: \d{4}){2}`: Match a space followed by 4 digits. Repeat this group 2 times to make sure to match 3 sets separated by a single space.
- `\b`: Word boundary

Comment: Actually I made mistake while asking question I was looking for 3 occurrence instead of 4 so I changed this `(?: \d{4}){3}` to this `(?: \d{4}){2}` you can change it in your answer & in [RegExDemo](https://regex101.com/r/F6Ij3i/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `(?:\s*\b\d{4}\b){4}`

Comment: That requires a starting space, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: I tweaked it a bit, that should solve it now.

Comment: Just to note that that also matches `'     1234     1234    1234    1234  '`. Not sure if that's the OP's intention.